# ng-show "call method" doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and going through w3schools tutorials i created my own example where ng-show calls method to remove elements after ng-click event.

When i click on button, it calls `HidePerson()` method. further it calls  `ShowPerson()`  method many times and it seems to work find, BUT whenever it returns `true` or  `false` elements are always visible.

Here is my code.

```js
var personCtrl = angular.module('person', []);
personCtrl.controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.persons = [];
    $scope.personIgnoreList = [];
    $scope.GetPersons = function () {
        $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php')
        .success(function (data, obj1, obj2, obj3) {
            $scope.persons = data;
        })
         .error(function (data, obj1, obj2, obj3) {
             $scope.persons = "Ops... smth went wrong...";
         })
    };

    $scope.ShowPerson = function (person) {
        $($scope.personIgnoreList).each(function (i, p) {
            if (p == person) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    $scope.HidePerson = function (person) {
        $scope.personIgnoreList.push(person);
      
    }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="person" class="container" ng-controller="personCtrl" ng-init="GetPersons()">
    <div class="row">
        <div  class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <div ng-show="ShowPerson(person)">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info"
                        ng-click="HidePerson(person)">
                    {{person.Name}} from {{person.City}} - {{person.Country}}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could also try to use `ng-if`

Comment: `$($scope.personIgnoreList).each(function (i, p) {` -- don't use jQuery in an Angular app like that...

Comment: don't use jQuery in angular at all, that kind of stuff you should do it with directives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code

```
$($scope.personIgnoreList).each(function (i, p) {
    if (p == person) {
        return false;
    }
});
return true;
```

you always return `true`, because returning from `$.each` is not the same as returning from function (it will just break the loop).

Correct approach would be using something like this:

```
$scope.ShowPerson = function (person) {
    return !$scope.personIgnoreList.some(function(p) {
        return p === person;
    });
}
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yGy8x2k25Dkpu6hLj4eu?p=preview

Comment: you are still using jQuery in angularJS

Comment: @FrancescoE. jQuery is not the issue here.

Comment: but still why to use jQuery for a forEach?

Comment: That's true, but still it's not an issue. For example in your answer you still have the same problem, even though you use `angular.forEach`.

Comment: well, let's say that you modified with my advice to do not use jQuery and I did the same with my answer, that's cooperation!

Comment: Well I don't use jQuery in my answer, so nothing to modify for me :)

Comment: so what is that `$($scope.personIgnoreList).each(function (i, p)`?

Comment: This is original OP's code, which I explained why it doesn't work. Then I added my working answer.

Comment: The problem was inside JQuery each loop.... by returning true inside each loop, it doesnt exit  ShowPerson  function by returning false value. instead it just exits each function and returns false.... always!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use jQuery in angularJS, and in your case is useless, you can change the forEach like so:

```
    $scope.ShowPerson = function (person) {
        var show = true;
        angular.forEach($scope.personIgnoreList, function (p, i) {
            if (p == person) {
                show= false;
            }
        });
        return show;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Array` has the methods `some` and `every` that allow you to do those kind of tests.

```
$scope.ShowPerson = function (person) {
  return $scope.personIgnoreList.every(function(p) {
           return p != person;
          });
};
```

For every person in `personIgnoreList` `some` tests if it is not equal to `person`. If it is, then it breaks and returns `false`.

Note: `every` isn't available in IE 8.